# How do define which spider the scrapy shell uses?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to test out some XPaths using the Scrapy shell, but it seems to be calling on my incomplete spider module to do the scraping, which is not what I want. Is there a way to define which spider scrapy uses with its shell? Even more, why is Scrapy doing this; shouldn't it know the spider is not ready for use? That's why I'm using the shell right? Otherwise I'd be using

```
scrapy crawl spider_name
```

if I wanted to use a specific spider.

Edit: After looking at the Spider docs forever, I found the following description for the spider instance used in the shell.

spider - the Spider which is known to handle the URL, or a BaseSpider object if there is no spider found for the current URL

This means, scrapy has correlated the URL with my spider, and is using it instead of a BaseSpider. Unfortunately, my spider is not ready for testing, so is there a way to force it to use a BaseSpider for the shell instead?

Comment: If you're trying to debug your spider, you might want to see this section of the docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses

Comment: I'm not trying to debug my spider, rather debug an XPath. This is done using the Scrapy shell, but the shell seems to be creating an instance of my defined spider, not the default BaseSpider class.

Comment: @ThomasK the url is not available now :(

Comment: @Weixiao.Fan: It seems they've restructured the docs a bit. Try this: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scrapy automatically selects the spider based on the `allowed_domains` attribute. If there are more than one spider for given domain Scrapy will use `BaseSpider`.

But, it's just a python shell, you can instantiate any spider you want.

```
>>> from myproject.spiders.myspider import MySpider
>>> spider = MySpider()
>>> spider.parse_item(response)
```

Edit: as workaround to **not** use your spider you can set `allowed_domains = []`

Answer (score 1):

The [shell isn't intended to be used with a spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/shell.html):

> You can try and debug your scraping
>   code very quickly, without having to
>   run the spider. ... [It] is used for testing XPath expressions.

Comment: I understand, and that's what I'm trying to do but it creates an instance of my defined spider class instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your settings file to change `DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS`

Per the docs :

> The default class that will be used
>   for instantiating items in the the
>   Scrapy shell.

Comment: Although this wasn't the exact right answer, changing `SPIDER_MODULES = []` in the settings.py did the trick.